# How to make facebook like button display minimum count as 0 in box count?

Tags: facebook, count, facebook-like, minimum

How to display the box count forcefully even when there are no likes? It should display minimum count of 0 if no likes. This, to remove the space between like button and button placed next to it.

Thank you.

Comment: But I have already seen many sites doing that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a design hack I've used:
http://revisedagain.com/2012/design-hack-facebook-like-button_count-0-count/